# Only Custom segues support class names prior to iOS 9.0

Tags: ios, xcode, segue, uistoryboardsegue, ios9

In Xcode 7 GM, I'm getting the above warning in my storyboard. What does it mean?

I do have some Custom segues, and they have their class assigned to a transition manager (UIStoryboardSegue). I checked all my segues in the storyboard, and all the custom segues have a custom class, and all non-custom segues don't have a custom class assigned (including unwind segues).

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?  I am targeting iOS 7, and I used to call `segueForUnwindingToViewController` in a custom Navigation Controller which returns either my custom unwind segues or calls the same method on `super`.  Now you can enter your unwind segue class in storyboard, but is this backwards compatible?

Comment: I watched the WWDC 2015 video on Storyboards, and apparently segueForUnindingToViewController is still supported if your target supports both 8 and 9.

Comment: I did too... how do you remove the warning?

Comment: That, I don't know. I don't think you can if you are targeting both 8 and 9.

Comment: I was getting same warning due to segue to different storyboard and having a custom "Segue" class, which also cause app crash on iOS8.

Answer (score 7):

To resolve this warning change **segue with custom class** to **Custom**[image]

Of course logic with performing the transition should be implemented in that class (ExternalStoryboardSegue in my case)

Comment: All my segues with a custom class are set to Custom, and I still get the warning.

Comment: Thanks. I've try this and it seems it fix my problem. Never thought that it has Custom mode.

Comment: @HotJard How did you do with unwind segues?

Comment: @MarieDm I'm trying to suppress the "Only custom segues" warning with unwind segues too.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: In Xcode 8, I still have this warning.. even if I set for not using custom segue..   And when I reset to previous commit and set again, warning is gone.. I think this kinda bug of xcode

Comment: This doesn't work for me either, anyone have any workarounds for this?